# Bxslider don't initiated with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, carousel, bxslider

I have a problem with bxloader and `requirejs`.
I invite a module with a bxslider per require.js in my app.
Unfortunately bxloader doesn't initialize.

My View.html

```
<div class="slider5" >
<div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
 <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "lib/jquery",
        "jquery.bxslider":"lib/jquery.bxslider"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery.bxslider": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "bxslider"
 }
```

After debugging, I have found that length of my slider elements (length == 0):
bxslider.js

```
$.fn.bxSlider = function(options){

if(this.length == 0) return this;
```

How can it be?Any thoughts?

```
define(["app",'jquery', "jquery.bxslider", "text!tpl/movingbox.html"], function(App, $,  InitBxSlider, movingboxTpl) {
    App.module("Movingbox", function( Movingbox, App, $, _, bxslider) {

        Movingbox.onStart = function(bxslider) {
            $('.slider5').bxSlider({
                    slideWidth: 400,
                    minSlides: 9,
                    maxSlides: 9,
                    moveSlides: 1,
                    slideMargin: 10,
                    infiniteLoop:true,
                    controls:true,
                    pager:false

                  });

        }
```

Comment: Please add the code that calld `$(...).bxSlider(..)` to your question.

Comment: Hi Louis, 
i have added call

Comment: Is the view already present in the DOM by the time that code executes?

Comment: View is shown without slider function, because slider was not initialized

Comment: no, views are loaded, after the scripts was executed. Is it possible initialize bxslider,  after the views are loaded?

Comment: I think the problem in my case is that bxslider plugin will not exported correctly:

  "jquery.bxslider": {
             deps: ["jquery"],
             exports, "bxslider" /*undefined*/
         },

I don't know how I can it  resolve

Comment: I have same problema and finally i findtout that jquery is not find any item. Try to test your jquery selector if it is find the element:  $('.slider5').length != 0